# iPhone front camera mirror

Tags: iphone, ios, camera

My app is working with iPhone's front camera. When Iam trying to capture my photo there is an issue.
When I am turn left In the camera it is showing like turn right. Just like a mirror. How can I avoid this?!

```
AVCaptureDeviceInput *newVideoInput;
AVCaptureDevicePosition currentCameraPosition = [[videoInput device] position];

if (currentCameraPosition == AVCaptureDevicePositionBack)
{
    currentCameraPosition = AVCaptureDevicePositionFront;
}
else
{
    currentCameraPosition = AVCaptureDevicePositionBack;
}

AVCaptureDevice *backFacingCamera = nil;
NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
for (AVCaptureDevice *device in devices) 
{
    if ([device position] == currentCameraPosition)
    {
        backFacingCamera = device;
    }
}
newVideoInput = [[AVCaptureDeviceInput alloc] initWithDevice:backFacingCamera error:&error];
```

Comment: I faced same issue. +1 for this!

Comment: When you capture a snapshot or record a video it will be in proper mode. Any camera you use will show you mirror picture but actual output after recording it will normal.